# Compile-time defined storage order in Fortran using C++ preprocessor

Tags: boost, fortran, c-preprocessor

I would like get a flexible (compile time defined) storage order in Fortran 90. For this I'm trying to use a C++ preprocessor including some boost pp headers.

So, for example, instead of accessing a 3D-array like this:

```
myArray(k,i,j)
```

I'd like to have this:

```
myArray(POINT3D(i,j,k))
```

and determine the order of accesses at compile time.

Now what I've tried:

```
#include "boost_pp_cat.hpp"
#include "boost_pp_comma.hpp"

! ------ Define storage orders here --------- !
!Forward lookup {i,j,k} <- {1,2,3}
#define KIJ_ORDER_ARG1 k
#define KIJ_ORDER_ARG2 i
#define KIJ_ORDER_ARG3 j

! ------ Switch between storage orders ------ !
#define CURR_ORDER KIJ_ORDER

! ------ Generate all required macros ------- !
#define STOR_ORDER_ARG(storOrder, argNum) BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_CAT(storOrder, _ARG), argNum)

#define CHOOSE_PARAM(storOrder, argNum) BOOST_PP_CAT(STOR_ORDER_ARG(storOrder, argNum), Param)

#define POINT3D(iParam, jParam, kParam) POINT3D_WITH_STORORDER(CURR_ORDER, iParam, jParam, kParam)

#define POINT3D_WITH_STORORDER(storOrder, iParam, jParam, kParam)     POINT3D_WITH_STORORDER_PRE(storOrder) 
#define POINT3D_WITH_STORORDER_PRE(storOrder) CHOOSE_PARAM(storOrder, 1), CHOOSE_PARAM(storOrder, 2), CHOOSE_PARAM(storOrder, 3)
```

This will expand

```
myArray(POINT3D(i,j,k))
```

to

```
myArray(kParam, iParam, jParam)
```

.

Almost there! Now my question:

1. Is it possible to do what I want using a C preprocessor?
2. If not - what technique would you use? (I'm thinking about making my own specialized "preprocessor" python script, but do you have another suggestion?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone reads this: I settled for the solution below. Not as elegant, extendable or reusable but it gets the job done and lets me use the 'standard' fortran preprocessor without extensions (a big plus when you have to debug your code since the line numbers of the original file can be shown).

```
! ------ Define storage orders here --------- !
#define IJK_ORDER 1
#define KIJ_ORDER 2
#define IKJ_ORDER 3
! ------ Switch between storage orders ------ !
#ifdef GPU
  #define CURR_ORDER IJK_ORDER
#else
  #define CURR_ORDER KIJ_ORDER
#endif

! ------ Order dependent macros ------------- !
#if (CURR_ORDER == KIJ_ORDER)
  #define AT(iParam, jParam, kParam) kParam, iParam, jParam
#elif (CURR_ORDER == IKJ_ORDER)
  #define AT(iParam, jParam, kParam) iParam, kParam, jParam
#else
  #define AT(iParam, jParam, kParam) iParam, jParam, kParam
#endif

! ------ general macros --------------------- !
!note: this is just a rename. Same syntax can be used for domain definition and array access
!-> give it two seperate names to make the intention of the code clearer
#define DOM(iParam, jParam, kParam) AT(iParam, jParam, kParam)
```

Answer (score 1):

1: I don't know, but personally I wouldn't rely on a preprocessor for this sort of operation anyway.

2: I'd write a Fortran defined type along these lines

```
   type odd_storage_order_real_array
        integer, dimension(3) :: permutation
        real, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: elements
      contains
        procedure :: get_element_at
    end type odd_storage_order_real_array
```

you could then write statements such as

```
type(odd_storage_order_real_array) :: an_array
.
.
.
an_array%get_element_at(1,2,3)
```

to get the element at the location specified.  You'll notice I've not written the `get_element_at` function for you, but your question suggests to me that you won't have any trouble writing it yourself.  Of course, it would use the `permutation` component to reorder the indices as you want.  And you might want a corresponding `set_element_at` function, and functions for 'type-casting' to and from the inbuilt arrays.

If you want to have a single type for arrays of any rank, flatten them out like this:

```
type odd_storage_order_real_array
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: permutation
    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: elements
  contains
    procedure :: element_at
end type odd_storage_order_real_array
```

**EDIT**

in response to OP's comment. I still wouldn't use a preprocessor.

I think what I'd do in this case is write a function to transpose (generalising to as many dimensions as you like) an array from its 'natural' order to its required order, and write the inverse of that function too.  On initialisation apply the function, on finalisation the inverse function; the execution costs shouldn't be significant.  Whether this suits the pattern of your application I don't know.

What I'd really do is try a few variations and see which one gives me the best ratio of performance:programmability; in other words, there are limits to how unreadable (and unmaintainable etc) I'll make an HPC code in the search for speed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is something I haven't mentioned yet: This is supposed to be for a HPC task. Your answer might be applicable iff the accessors can be inlined and expanded to constants by the compiler, otherwise it would hurt performance quite a bit. I will have to test it then.